# How to use inline template with multiple inputs in MVC Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Inside my view I currently have

```
@{
    Func<Website.Security.User[], object> renderUserList = @<text>
        <div class="span4">
            @*<h2>@title</h2>*@
            <ul>
                @foreach (var user in item)
                {
                    <li>@user.UserName - <a href="/Config/User/Edit/@user.UserName">Edit</a></li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </text>;
}
@renderUserList(Model.AdminUsers)
```

How can I rework this so that the renderUserList expression can take in a second input for the section title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand, you trying to create helper: [ASP.NET MVC 3 and the @helper syntax within Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)

```
   @helper renderUserList(Website.Security.User[] users, string title)
   {
        <div class="span4"> 
            <h2>@title</h2> 
            <ul> 
                @foreach (var user in users) 
                { 
                    <li>@user.UserName - <a href="/Config/User/Edit/@user.UserName">Edit</a></li> 
                } 
            </ul> 
        </div> 
    }
```

Comment: This works except you forgot to include the second parameter in the method, but works for me